# identify handlebar brand

Tags: handlebars

I have a triathlon bike with this handle bar. I can't find the name of the manufacturer. I tried to search WISE like written in the logo but it doesn't give any results. 
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Found this company: https://gdwise.en.alibaba.com/

Comment: I'd guess that the bike manufacturer either make their own handlebars in house, or get someone else to make them and re-brand them.   Have you tried contacting Wise ?